# Excel macro to change background color

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

I'm working on a simple Excel macro to change the background color depending of the cell value. This is basically to display an image in Excel. However, the following code causes Excel to crash with no apparent reason.

```vb
Option Explicit


Sub SetBgColor()
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler

    Dim Data As Worksheet
    Set Data = Sheets("Data")

    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long

    Dim MaxRows As Long
    MaxRows = 693

    Dim MaxCols As Long
    MaxCols = 400


    Dim CellVal As Integer
    For i = 1 To Rows.Count
        For j = 1 To MaxCols
            CellVal = Data.Cells(i, j).Value Mod 255

            If i Mod 3 = 0 Then
                Data.Cells(i, j).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, CellVal)
            ElseIf i Mod 3 = 1 Then
                Data.Cells(i, j).Interior.Color = RGB(CellVal, 0, 0)
            ElseIf i Mod 3 = 2 Then
                Data.Cells(i, j).Interior.Color = RGB(0, CellVal, 0)
            End If
        Next j
    Next i

ErrHandler:
Dim Msg As String

If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    Msg = "Error #" & Str(Err.Number) & " generated by " & Err.Source & Chr(13) _
        & "Error Line: " & Erl & Chr(13) _
        & Chr(13) _
        & Err.Description

    MsgBox Msg, , "Error", Err.HelpFile, Err.HelpContext
End If

End Sub
```

The worksheet contains 400 columns and 693 rows. The macro starts correctly but Excel crashes randomly in the process and I can't say why.

I've added the error handling code but nothing is showing.

Also, is there a more efficient way than looping over each columns and rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub SetBgColor()
On Error GoTo ErrHandler

Dim Data    As Worksheet
Set Data = Sheets("Data")

Dim i       As Long
Dim j       As Long

With Data
    Dim MaxRows As Long
    MaxRows = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row    ' assuming Column A (1) has the most data

    Dim MaxCols As Long
    MaxCols = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column    ' assuming your row 1 has the most column data

    Dim CellVal As Integer
    For i = 1 To MaxRows
        For j = 1 To MaxCols
            CellVal = .Cells(i, j).Value Mod 255
            If i Mod 3 = 0 Then
                .Cells(i, j).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, CellVal)
            ElseIf i Mod 3 = 1 Then
                .Cells(i, j).Interior.Color = RGB(CellVal, 0, 0)
            ElseIf i Mod 3 = 2 Then
                .Cells(i, j).Interior.Color = RGB(0, CellVal, 0)
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
End With                     'Data

Exit Sub

ErrHandler:
Dim Msg     As String

If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    Msg = "Error #" & Str(Err.Number) & " generated by " & Err.Source & Chr(13) _
          & "Error Line: " & Erl & Chr(13) _
          & Chr(13) _
          & Err.Description

    MsgBox Msg, , "Error", Err.HelpFile, Err.HelpContext
End If

End Sub
```

The main issue, I think, was you were looping over **all rows** in the worksheet, which can take a long time and possibly crash the workbook.  Instead, I changed your first `For` loop to `For i = 1 to MaxRows`.

Other than that, I did a little tweaking to make the macro more dynamic and avoid "hard coded" numbers where I could.  This assumes your column A has the most data, and row 1 includes the most column data.

Comment: I tried with your changes but Excel is still freezing. :(

Comment: Hum I was just a bit impatient. It's working fine. :)

Comment: @Spack - You also may want to add `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` to the very beginning of the macro. That way it doesn't use up processing time actually showing you each cell changing.  Then at the end, just do `Application.ScreenUpdating = True`.

Comment: In this situation, I want to see the image building progesssively.

Answer (score 1):

Excel was in fact freezing in the loop with no way to refresh its window and therefore looking like stuck.

The solution is to call `DoEvents` in the loop.

```vb
For i = 1 To MaxRows
    For j = 1 To MaxCols
        CellVal = .Cells(i, j).Value Mod 255
        If i Mod 3 = 0 Then
            .Cells(i, j).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, CellVal)
        ElseIf i Mod 3 = 1 Then
            .Cells(i, j).Interior.Color = RGB(CellVal, 0, 0)
        ElseIf i Mod 3 = 2 Then
            .Cells(i, j).Interior.Color = RGB(0, CellVal, 0)
        End If
    Next j
    DoEvents
Next i
```